# First adjacent difference larger than a value

Tags: python, difference

I have a Series of measurements. I want to select the first measurement in that series where the adjacent difference is greater than a certain number and index it's position.
For example, if I set the max difference to be 4 and I have

values = [5,6,5,10,17,11,13]

I want it to return 5 and 3

Because 5 is the first difference between two adjacent numbers that is larger than 4, and 3 is the index where the difference occurs. 
Is there a simple command to do this in Python?

Comment: No command just logic ,you just need to iterate through the list, compare [i-1] and [i+1] if they are different and get the subtract between them. Sound like a homework problem for me

Answer (score 0):

There's no command, but you can do this:

```
l = [5,6,5,10,13,11,13]
diffs = [y-x for x, y in zip(l, l[1:])]
next(x for x in enumerate(diffs, start=1) if x[1] > 1)
```

This outputs: `(3, 5)`

Comment: So, the issue is I don't want to find the maximum difference. I want to find the first time the difference is larger than a certain value. I'll update my question to make this more clear.

Comment: Does this answer the question?